# AWK to check a string pattern and extract it from a file

Tags: unix, awk

Below are the file contents:

```
{30001002|XXparameter|XSD_LOC|$\{FILES_DIR\}/xsd/EDXFB_mbr_demo.xsd|3|2|$|@{0|}}
{30001002|XXparameter|source_files|$XSD/EDXFB_mbr_demo.xsd|3|1|l|@{0|}}
```

I trying to accomplish below using awk:
Firstly I want to search for string Pattern "EDXFB*.xsd".
If exists, then extract the strings that starts with "EDXFB" and ends with ".xsd"

Output:

```
EDXFB_mbr_demo.xsd
EDXFB_mbr_demo.xsd
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic awk pattern to extract the expression and print out matched data is following:

```
gawk 'match($0, /EDXFB.+\.xsd/, a) { print a[0] }'
```

Though, you should really spend some time reading `awk` manual.

And the regular expression could be changed to `/EDXFB[a-z_]+\.xsd/` if it contains only lower-cased characters and `_`.

**[EDIT]**: Updated with cleaner code from **@JID**. Thanks :)

Comment: GNU awk `awk 'match($0, /EDXFB.+\.xsd/,a){print a[0]}'`

Comment: Even shorter: `awk 'match($0,/EDXFB.+\.xsd/,a)&&$0=a[0]'`

Comment: @Jotne - I guess you would win @ http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
awk -F/ '/EDXFB.*\.xsd/ {split($NF,a,"|");print a[1]}' file
EDXFB_mbr_demo.xsd
EDXFB_mbr_demo.xsd
```

It separate the line by `/` then print last field until `|`

Answer (score 1):

In your example, probably grep would do what you want:

```
grep -o 'EDXFB.*\.xsd'
```

Comment: Note this requires GNU grep

Comment: @JID, I was planning to write a more complex version `EBXFB.*?\.xsd(?=\|)` but I believe a simple grep is what OP is looking for...